# Controller not passing in values from the from to the create method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My Create controller passes in the for the child of a nested resource as null instead of passing the values i've just inputed into the form.

Here is my code

**Routes:**

```
resources :trips do
 resources :pilgrims
end
```

**Models:**

*Trip:*

```
 class Trip < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :pilgrims 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :pilgrims, :allow_destroy => true
  attr_accessible :end_date, :leader_id, :name, :start_date, :pilgrim_attributes

 end
```

*Pilgrim:*

```
 class Pilgrim < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :trip 
    attr_accessible :pilgrim_id, :surname, :name, :middle, :aka, :prefix, :address, :city, :state, :zip, :email, :telephone, :nationality, :date_of_birth, :passport_number, :expiration, :jordan, :room, :price, :status, :trip_id

 end
```

My Pilgrim controller:

```
 def new
  @trip = Trip.find(params[:trip_id])
  @pilgrim = Pilgrim.new
 end

def create
  @trip = Trip.find(params[:trip_id])
  @pilgrim = @trip.pilgrims.build(params[:pilgrim])


  if @pilgrim.save
    flash[:notice] = "The <b>#{ @pilgrim.name }</b> has been created successfully."
    redirect_to(trip_pilgrims_path, :notice => "The <b>#{ @pilgrim.name }</b> ship has been saved successfully.")
  else
    render(:new, :error => @pilgrim.errors)
  end
 end
```

Link to a gist with my form code [Form](https://gist.github.com/4577016)

The routes seem to be correct, when i click on new_trip_pilgrim_path(@trip) it does point to trips/:trip_id/pilgrims/new and loads the new pilgrim form.

However when i click save on the form it redirects me to the route trips/3/pilgrims but shows the new pilgrim form saying all required fields were left blank.

This is what displays in the log.

```
Started POST "/trips/3/pilgrims" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-01-19 22:12:06 -0800
Processing by PilgrimsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"kOE06m3DNax43BOLYZ6t1lS7/T4wOWb2xM8m/mlQzvA=", "commit"=>"Create Pilgrim", "trip_id"=>"3"}
Trip Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `trips`.* FROM `trips` WHERE `trips`.`id` = 3 LIMIT 1
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
(0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
Pilgrim Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `pilgrims`.* FROM `pilgrims` WHERE `pilgrims`.`trip_id` = 3
Rendered pilgrims/_form.html.erb (36.4ms)
Rendered pilgrims/new.html.erb within layouts/application (37.2ms)
User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
Trip Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `trips`.* FROM `trips` 
Completed 200 OK in 244ms (Views: 102.5ms | ActiveRecord: 11.2ms)
```

What is going on with the Pilgrim create controller?

Comment: You seem to have posted the code for `Trip` twice, and none for `Pilgrim`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create a new pilgrim object by calling

```
@pilgrim = @trip.pilgrims.build(params[:pilgrim])
```

in the PilgrimsController. But `Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"kOE06m3DNax43BOLYZ6t1lS7/T4wOWb2xM8m/mlQzvA=", "commit"=>"Create Pilgrim", "trip_id"=>"3"}` Doesn't contain any pilgrim paramters. So the problem is with the form used for creating a new pilgrim

Comment: @Hillary what does the HTML output look like?